Comment peut-on éviter la répétition dans ce paragraphe
Comment peut-on éviter la répétition dans le paragraphe suivant ?
Les livres, les articles et les journaux sont utilisés pour … (reste de la phrase). Les livres, les articles et les journaux qu'on a utilisés sont : … (liste d'articles et livres).

peut-on dire: "Les livres, les articles et les journaux sont utilisés pour ... (rest de la phrase) . les uns qu'on a utilisé sont ..."?

Je comprends infiniment mieux le pb. avec ce commentaire.

Les livres, articles et journaux {furent utilisés pour | servirent à} [bla bla bla]. CEUX qu'on a utilisés sont: [liste de documents].
